# mock rest api call during integration test in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, spring-test

I have a spring boot service that validates each request by calling my auth service. Now I am writing an integration test. How can I mock my request to auth service while testing my own APIs?

```
@GetMapping("/pending/task")
    @Operation(summary = "Get user's pending task", tags = "UserTask", security = {@SecurityRequirement(name = Constants.AUTH_TOKEN_HEADER)})
    @PreAuthorize(Constants.PreAuthorize.ROLE)
    public List<UserTaskDto> getPendingTasks(@Valid @RequestParam long courseId){
        // internal logic
    }
SpringBoot filter will read the token from the header and verify that against auth service using rest. I want to mock that call during this api testing.
```

Test Code

```
class UserTaskControllerTest extends ApplicationTests {

@Mock
RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Test
void shouldGiveAllUserPendingTask(){
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(Constants.AUTH_TOKEN_HEADER, GENERIC_AUTH_TOKEN);
    Task task = FactoryClass.createTask();
    UserTask userTask = FactoryClass.createUserTask();
    CentralAuthInfo centralAuthInfo = FactoryClass.getCentralAuthInfo();
    taskRepository.save(task);
    userTask.setTask(task);
    userTaskRepository.save(userTask);
    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(USER_PENDING_TASK_BASE_URL)
            .queryParam(COURSE_ID, userTask.getCohortId());

    when(restTemplate.exchange(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpMethod.class), ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpEntity.class), ArgumentMatchers.eq(CentralAuthInfo.class))).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(centralAuthInfo, HttpStatus.OK));
    ResponseEntity<UserTaskDto> responseEntity = testRestTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(), GET, new HttpEntity<>(headers), UserTaskDto.class);
    assertThat(responseEntity.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(200);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring offers a `@WithMockUser` that you can add to your tests. I usually use it with a `WebTextClient` to test API calls. Here is an example with reactive controller but same applies to non-reactive

```
@Import(SecurityConfig.class)
@WebFluxTest(MyController.class)
class MyControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;
...
    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username="admin",roles={"USER","ADMIN", "ROLE"})
    void testPendingTasks() {
        webTestClient
                .get()
                .uri("/pending/task")
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus()
                .isOk();
    }
...
}
```

Comment: this will not work. My filter calls my other service to validate tokens. I want to mock that call but mock does not work for that as I am writing an integration test.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)` will help to disable security for integration test, like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
public class FooTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    // some of your tests here ....
}
```

If it's not what you need you can just create a fake auth service class for test purposes and override the behavior in the way you want.